# Visual studio, F11, only stepping interested in what a particular thread is doing?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

Im just wondering if anyone knows if its possible to setup the debuger such that <kbd>F11</kbd> is only interested in a single thread? I have two threads running atm but im only interested in 1 of them. As such i dont want the screen to keep jumping further up the page to show me what the 1st thread is doing. Id like to set it up such that it only shows what the 2nd thread is doing.

Any pointers would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it would be to freeze the thread you are not interested in.

In Visual Studio, show the "Threads" window, available from the Debug->Windows menu.

Then, while you are tracing using <kbd>F11</kbd>, if the debugger breaks in the thread you are not interested in, find this thread in the threads window, right-click it and choose the "Freeze" option in the context menu.

Now when you continue to trace using <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>F11</kbd>, you will never hit breakpoints in the frozen thread.

Note that the frozen thread will not be executing at all, so if you do need it to do some work while you are debugging, you may need to unfreeze and freeze it again from time to time.

Comment: +1 correct answer. But I was shocked that the feature to automatically freeze other threads upon break does not exists as I saw here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/86f0b04b-ce91-4e5a-b694-67b802928fe3/is-it-possible-to-make-single-thread-debugging-the-default-behaviour-in-a-multithreaded-program?forum=vsdebug

Answer (score 1):

If you open the debugger's "Threads" window you'll see that there's a "Just My Code" flag for each thread.  I've found that if you set the flag for only the current thread that you're stepping through, the "Step into" (<kbd>F11</kbd>) and "Step over" (<kbd>F10</kbd>) functions seem to target only that thread.  While this targets native threads, it works just as well for managed code using threads.

However, the functionality can be pretty fragile if you're not careful - breakpoints will still break for any thread (unless the breakpoint is filtered to be only for the thread of interest).  And if another thread is in the middle of being stepped before you set this flag, that thread may still 'interact' with the debugger while you're trying to step through the current thread.  So you'll need to carefully manage your breakpoints while using this feature.

However, all-in-all it seems to work really well.

Note that I think the terminology is quite confusing since "Just My Code" is also used to describe a managed debugger feature for setting the debugger to not bother stepping into 'non-user' code (which is controlled by attributes on methods).  The native thread "Just My Code" is something different, and I actually can't find much in the way of documentation ([How to: Flag and Unflag Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385628.aspx)).  This particular behavior of targeting a single thread for stepping doesn't seem to be mentioned - I stumbled on it by accident.